# Get last post in category thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails, categories

I want make a button to filter posts from a specific category, But also i would like this button to display the featured image of the latest post in that category.

I'm completly new to php and wordpress, but i tought maybe using the `get_category` and `get_thumbnail`functions may be a good way to go.

What do you guys think? 
I am sorry for the vagueness, but I am a little lost about this.
Thanks for any hints in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=1&cat=55' );
    if($the_query->have_posts()) : 
        while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();?>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a>
 <?php endwhile;
    endif;
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Replace cat=55 with the category ID you want and/or replace showposts=1 with the number of latest posts you want to show if you want more than 1.

If you want a different size for your thumbnail, you can use one of the followings (taken from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail):

```
the_post_thumbnail();                  // without parameter -> 'post-thumbnail'
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail('medium');          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail('large');           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
the_post_thumbnail('full');            // Full resolution (original size uploaded)
the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) );  // Other resolutions
```

Comment: I can use this code wherever in the page? or do i have to paste it in a specific file? (sorry for the total ignorance)

Comment: @invicente where are you trying to show this?

Comment: in the main home

Comment: just paste it into the template file where you want it to show up.

Comment: even though IT IS working, it's failing to recognize the specific ID of the category I chose. it always displays the thumbnails from the same cat, with any number.... what could be the problem?

Comment: my bad... it is supposed to be cat not catID. try that and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I see you edited your answer too, thanks for the help!